# When is directadmin user detail (especially bandwidth) updated? Possible to be online?

Tags: bandwidth, users

I hope it be the right place for asking about Directadmin, cpanel and other moderation web application. (I've deleted my question from pro webmaster site at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com and have moved to here)

Why shouldn't bandwidth usage and other user details be online in the page: http://domain.com:2222/CMD_SHOW_USER?user=myuser titled Details for User myuser?

When is that updated? There should a be cron job. How can it be configured? Is that possible via DA admin interface?

Comment: Thank you Kenny. I tagged "direct-admin" but as few questions have the tag, the system didn't let me use it.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sort of data is updated when `tally` runs. This occurs usually every day at 00:10, but you can check the file `/etc/cron.d/directadmin_cron` where Directadmin's crons are defined.